# String operation performance optimization

Tags: bash

I have a large file (~60Mb) filled with path of files and directories.

I need to check each path and then pad them or shorten them based on their size. So, I am using the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

lines="$(cat $HOME/plocate-index.txt)"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $lines
do
    if [[ ${#line} -gt 100 ]] ; then
        echo ${line:$((${#line}-100))}
        continue
    else
        filler_length=$((100-${#line}+1))
        filler=$(seq -s '.' 1 $filler_length | tr -dc '.')
        echo "${filler}${line}"
    fi
done > $HOME/plocate-index-fixed.txt
```

To index the whole file system and create `$HOME/plocate-index.txt`, it takes around 2 seconds. But to pad or shorten the path (run the given script) it takes, i do not know, i had to press <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>.

Is there any way i can speed up this process.

**Update 1:**

The bellow code is now benchmarkable (takes around a minute), however it need to be faster, otherwise will kill the UX.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if [[ ${#line} -gt 100 ]] ; then
        echo ${line:$((${#line}-100))}
        continue
    else
        filler_length=$((100-${#line}+1))
        filler=$(seq -s '.' 1 $filler_length | tr -dc '.')
        echo "${filler}${line}"
    fi
done < "$HOME/plocate-index.txt" > "$HOME/plocate-index-fixed.txt"
```

Comment: Some reading: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Would a text processing program like awk be a possible solution ?

Comment: @Itération122442 i am happy with anything as long as it is fast.

Comment: What about `awk`?

Comment: @Dominique yes. But i can not write awk. If you can kindly provide the code then i can try.

Comment: So you want the rightmost 100 chars of a long line, or a short line with dots on the left? If GNU awk, `awk 'length>=100{print substr($0,length-99);next} {print gensub(" ",".","g",sprintf("%*s",100-length,"")) $0}' <infile >outfile` For other awks make the second action `{x=sprintf("%*s",100-length,""); gsub(" ",".",x); print x $0}`

Comment: Every time the `else` branch is taken, you create 3 child processes. No wonder that it takes long. I wonder why you are doing this in bash.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: no. my `gensub` operates on the output of `sprintf`, not `$0`; my `gsub` operates on `x` which is the output of `sprintf`, not `$0`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ooops, sorry, I saw parentheses where they were not.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : wouldn't your solution regenerate a new string of 100 dots every time it hits the `length >= 100` criteria ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: almost; it generates a new string of 100-length, not 100. Setting a string of 100 in BEGIN and using a substr of it would be an improvement, but Renaud's answer of using substr on the concatenation is even better.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : so it's still doing duplicative work - 5 rows of length 77 and it would generate 23 dots 5 times instead of once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) dots = dots "."}
  {print substr(dots $0, length($0) + 1, 100)}' \
  "$HOME/plocate-index.txt" > "$HOME/plocate-index-fixed.txt"
```

1. prepare a string of 100 dots in variable `dots`,
2. prepend `dots` to each line,
3. and print 100 characters starting from L+1 where L is the original line length.

With `sed` (tested with GNU `sed` but should work with any `sed`), which is sometimes faster than `awk` (but apparently not at all in this case):

```
printf -v dots '%100s' " "; dots="${dots// /.}"
sed -E "s/(.*)/$dots\1/;s/.*(.{100})/\1/" "$HOME/plocate-index.txt" > "$HOME/plocate-index-fixed.txt"
```

1. use bash to store a string of 100 dots in bash variable `dots`,
2. substitute each line with concatenation of `dots` and the line,
3. substitute the result with the 100 trailing characters,
4. and print (the default last action of `sed`).

Comment: 374132 lines in the blink of an eye.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76760809/1772898 Has a solution as well. However, the performance is killing me. Can you please give me the awk solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

> i am happy with anything as long as it is fast.

Here's a quick `perl` script to do it. Either reads from standard input or file names passed on the command line, prints to standard output.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my $length = 100;

my $pad = '.' x $length;

while (my $line = <<>>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (length($line) > $length) {
        say substr($line, -$length);
    } else {
        printf "%.*s%s\n", $length - length($line), $pad, $line;
    }
}
```

Example using a length of 10 for demonstration purposes:

```bash
$ cat input.txt
a line
another short line
$ perl pad.pl input.txt
....a line
short line
```

Though if you *really* want fast, there's C:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 100

int main(void) {
  char pad[LENGTH];
  memset(pad, '.', sizeof pad);

  char *line = NULL;
  size_t linelen = 0;
  ssize_t len;
  while ((len = getline(&line, &linelen, stdin)) > 0) {
    if (len > LENGTH) {
      fputs(line + (len - LENGTH - 1), stdout);
    } else {
      fwrite(pad, 1, LENGTH - len + 1, stdout);
      fputs(line, stdout);
    }
  }
  free(line);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AhmadIsmail Shell output redirection is your friend. Your attempts show you know how to do that.

Comment: Your solution is the fastest `237.00 millis`.

Comment: Compile it (`gcc -o pad -O -Wall -Wextra pad.c`), and then it reads from standard input and writes to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

instead of slowly looping, you can get all 100 dots in `awk` instantly :

---

```
mawk 'BEGIN { OFS = $0 = "."; NF = 100; print }'
```

---

simply save `$0` as another variable if you want to re-use that string of dots, and reset `$0 = ""` and `OFS = FS` before the first rows of data arrive.

And it's reasonably fast too :

- A single string of `33,554,432 (33.5 mn)` dots in `0.281 secs`.
- For ***only*** `65,536` dots, barely `0.006 secs`.

And if you need `4.29 billion` dots, `awk` can get that to you in `0.469 secs` :

```
( time ( mawk2 'BEGIN { OFS = "."
                         NF = 4^8 ;    gsub(OFS, $0)
                                    print length($0) }' 
) | gcat -b )

     1  4294836225

( mawk2 'BEGIN { ... }'; )  
          0.10s user 0.36s system 99% cpu 0.469 total
 gcat -b  0.00s user 0.00s system  0% cpu 0.409 total
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you're wondering, starting with 2 dots, this string concat chain yields 100 dots (`awk`) :

```
_ = (_=(_=(_ = "..") (_=(_)_)_)_) (_=(_)_)_ ;
```

It's merely leveraging the fact that `10 = 2 + 4 + 4`, and doing this twice to yield 100.

Comment: I think you have given two answers by mistake.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail : they're more related notes than a full solution anyway. but since we're on the topic, you can get from here to a single string of 100 million dots with just 2 calls of `gsub(".", _, _)`