# Append string at the end of streaming output which use an external command

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

indexDirectory1() {
    i=0
    while [ $i -ne 5 ]
    do
        if [ $i -eq 2 ]; then
            sleep 5;
        fi
        i=$(($i+1))
        echo "/home/ismail/First Function $i"
    done
}

indexDirectory2() {
    i=0
    while [ $i -ne 5 ]
    do
        if [ $i -eq 2 ]; then
            sleep 3;
        fi
        i=$(($i+1))
        echo "/home/ismail/Second Function $i"
    done
}

indexDirectory3() {
    i=0
    while [ $i -ne 5 ]
    do
        if [ $i -eq 2 ]; then
            sleep 1;
        fi
        i=$(($i+1))
        echo "/home/ismail/Third Function $i"
    done
}

export -f indexDirectory1
export -f indexDirectory2
export -f indexDirectory3

parallel -j3 ::: indexDirectory1 indexDirectory2 indexDirectory3
```

Here the output comes in three installments. I mean when a function is completely finished, its output is show.

Here the output looks like:

```
/home/ismail/Third Function 1
/home/ismail/Third Function 2
/home/ismail/Third Function 3
/home/ismail/Third Function 4
/home/ismail/Third Function 5
/home/ismail/Second Function 1
/home/ismail/Second Function 2
/home/ismail/Second Function 3
/home/ismail/Second Function 4
/home/ismail/Second Function 5
/home/ismail/First Function 1
/home/ismail/First Function 2
/home/ismail/First Function 3
/home/ismail/First Function 4
/home/ismail/First Function 5
```

Here I need output like:

```
/home/ismail/Third Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 1")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 2\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 2")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 3\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 3")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 4\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 4")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 5\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 5")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 1")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 2\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 2")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 3\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 3")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 4\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 4")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 5\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 5")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 1")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 2\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 2")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 3\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 3")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 4\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 4")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 5\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 5")\n
```

Where `get_icon_from_path` is a external command.

Just to clarify, I need this format to plug to rofi.

[rofi](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi) will need input like:

```
echo -en /home/ismail/Third Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 1")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Third Function 2\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 2")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Third Function 3\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 3")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Third Function 4\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 4")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Third Function 5\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 5")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Second Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 1")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Second Function 2\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 2")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Second Function 3\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 3")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Second Function 4\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 4")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/Second Function 5\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 5")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/First Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 1")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/First Function 2\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 2")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/First Function 3\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 3")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/First Function 4\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 4")\n
echo -en /home/ismail/First Function 5\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 5")\n
```

To function properly. I am saying this because of `echo -en`. the awk command need to keep `\0icon\x1f`, `\n` etc intact. More details is provided in the [documentation](https://davatorium.github.io/rofi/1.7.5/rofi-script.5/) under "Parsing row options" heading.

Here, i am only looking for the awk command to transform `parallel -j3 ::: indexDirectory1 indexDirectory2 indexDirectory3` output.

**Update 1:**

The following solution renders icons correctly but the performance is very poor. I think it is more than 10 minutes. Stopped benchmarking after a while.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    icon="$(get_icon_from_path "$line")"
    echo -en "$line"
    echo -en "\0icon\x1f${icon}\n"
done < <(parallel -j3 ::: indexDirectory1 indexDirectory2 indexDirectory3)
```

**Update 2:**

Here is the `get_icon_from_path` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gjs

const { Gio } = imports.gi;

let file = Gio.File.new_for_path(ARGV[0]);
let fileInfo = file.query_info('*', Gio.FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, null);
let icons = fileInfo.get_icon().get_names();

if (typeof icons[1] === 'undefined') {
    // does not exist
    print(icons[0]);
}
else {
    print(icons[1]);
}
```

**Update 3:**

Input is:

```
/home/ismail/Third Function 1
/home/ismail/Third Function 2
/home/ismail/Third Function 3
/home/ismail/Third Function 4
/home/ismail/Third Function 5
/home/ismail/Second Function 1
/home/ismail/Second Function 2
/home/ismail/Second Function 3
/home/ismail/Second Function 4
/home/ismail/Second Function 5
/home/ismail/First Function 1
/home/ismail/First Function 2
/home/ismail/First Function 3
/home/ismail/First Function 4
/home/ismail/First Function 5
```

Output is:

```
/home/ismail/Third Function 1\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 2\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 3\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 4\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 5\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 1\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 2\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 3\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 4\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 5\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/First Function 1\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/First Function 2\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/First Function 3\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/First Function 4\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
/home/ismail/First Function 5\0icon\x1f${icon}\n
```

Where:

- Here `${icon}` comes from running the command `echo $line`
- enable interpretation of backslash escapes (equivalent to `echo -e`)
- do not output the trailing newline  (equivalent to `echo -n`)

Comment: The expected output you want is not clear. Do you want **literally** `echo -en /home/ismail/Third Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 1")\n` with all backslashes and the leading `echo -en`? Do you want **literally** `/home/ismail/Third Function 1\0icon\x1f$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 1")\n` with all backslashes but without the leading `echo -en`? Something else? Do you want **literally** `$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 1")` or the result of its expansion by the shell?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet the code in **update 1**, in my question yield correct answer. I would like the awk command to do the same thing (hopefully faster).

Comment: Then `awk` will not be any faster (or marginally). What slows down the whole processing is this huge number of calls to this external `get_icon_from_path` command. An `awk` solution would have to call it too. Unless you can re-implement this `get_icon_from_path` command in plain `awk` there is no solution to your performance problem. Do you know what this command does?

Comment: I have added `get_icon_from_path` in **update 2**. If i get the awk command then I will also try `coproc`. Call `get_icon_from_path` using `coproc`.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an unambiguous example of output you expect from a `awk` script with the input you show. We don't need all the `rofi` details. All we need is the **exact literal** output you want with input `/home/ismail/Third Function 1`, etc.

Comment: Please check **Update 3:**. consider it to be the whole question.

Comment: Sorry, I give up, you are asking `awk` to solve a problem that it cannot. `awk` has no way to _run the command `echo $line`_ without... running it. Plus, if the value of `$line` is always the same there is no point in doing this and if it changes there is no way for `awk` to guess its value. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default GNU parallel's stdout is not line-buffered, it comes in per job wise (as in chunks). If you want to process one whole line at time,  you can ask it send the output line-buffered by enabling the `--line-buffer` option. But the line buffering would cause the outputs from each of the parallel running jobs mixed together i.e. in random order.

To achieve your desired result, use a simple command output iteration using a process-substitution `while` read loop and use `printf` to produce the desired string

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    icon="$(get_icon_from_path "$line")"
    printf '%s\\0icon\\x1f%s)\\n\n' "$line" "$icon"
done < <(parallel -j3 ::: indexDirectory1 indexDirectory2 indexDirectory3)
```

The double escapes near `\0`, `\x1` and `\n` are to prevent them from being interpreted as format codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254656/discussion-between-ahmad-ismail-and-inian).

Comment: @AhmadIsmail: Could you un-accept this answer please? I don't want to keep a non-working solution

Comment: You seem to be chasing a problem with using `rofi`, but the question or discussions in this post has nothing to do with that. Ideally you should be reaching out to the tool authors via GitHub or however it is maintained, to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

@Ahmad : you mean like this ?

```
jot 5 |
```

---

```
 mawk -v __='/home/ismail/' -- 'BEGIN { _ = "First Second Third "
            gsub("[^ ]+ ", (__) "&Function \\&\n", _) 
          } gsub(".+", _)' |

 mawk '$2 = $1' FS='\n' OFS='\\0icon\\33$(get_icon_from_path "' ORS='")\\n\n'
```

---

```
| gsort

/home/ismail/First Function 1\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 1")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 2\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 2")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 3\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 3")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 4\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 4")\n
/home/ismail/First Function 5\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/First Function 5")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 1\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 1")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 2\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 2")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 3\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 3")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 4\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 4")\n
/home/ismail/Second Function 5\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Second Function 5")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 1\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 1")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 2\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 2")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 3\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 3")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 4\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 4")\n
/home/ismail/Third Function 5\0icon\033$(get_icon_from_path "/home/ismail/Third Function 5")\n
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
appender() {
    perl -pe 'chomp;$_.="\\0icon\\x1f\$(get_icon_from_path \"$_\")\\n\n"'
}
export -f appender

parallel -j3 '{} | appender' ::: indexDirectory1 indexDirectory2 indexDirectory3
```

or:

```
parallel -j3 ::: indexDirectory1 indexDirectory2 indexDirectory3 | appender
```